# Subtraction in Ocaml, I can't quite nail down this bug

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

```
let rec sub' list1 list2 carry = match (list1, list2, carry) with
    | list1, [], 0       -> list1
    | [], list2, 0       -> list2
    | list1, [], carry   -> sub' list1 [carry] 0
    | [], list2, carry   -> sub' [carry] list2 0
    | car1::cdr1, car2::cdr2, carry ->
      let minus = car1 - car2 + carry



       in  minus mod radix :: sub' cdr1 cdr2 (minus / radix)
```

radix is set to 10

So, this is the code I have to subtract two numbers (list1 and list2). This is based on given code that I modified, so I'm not entirety sure how it works. It does work however, for most things. 5 - 4 = 1 10 - 20 = -10 etc.

But, it has this weird bug for larger numbers, 100 - 50 = "1-50" which is closeish, it has the "50" we want, but with some extra junk.

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and I'm rather stuck.

Edit:

```
let length    = List.length
let car       = List.hd
let cdr       = List.tl
let map       = List.map
let reverse   = List.rev
let strcat    = String.concat
let strlen    = String.length
let strsub    = String.sub
let zero      = Bigint (Pos, [])



let rec zeros' rev = 
if (car rev) = 0 then
  lead_zeros' (cdr rev)
else (reverse rev)

let zeros list = match list with
| [0] -> list
| [] -> []
| list -> let reversed = reverse list
          in lead_zeros' reversed
```

Comment: How to do "123" + "45" on paper? Because this code does not work like that. Subtraction and addition are the same fundamental operation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at. My addition works fine. 123 + 45 is 5+3, no carry, 4+6, no carry, 1+0. I'm not sure how to put new lines in comments, but I do remember how to add on paper.

Comment: can you give us an example of how you applied this `sub'` function to get the result of `5-4` , `10-20` and `100-50`

Comment: @JaneDoe `car :: cdr` - how to car/cdr map to the digits and the sequence of iteration? Unless the sequence of numeric digits is reversed (prior to call things function) this does not do '5+3' first.

Comment: @user2864740 Done see edit, and if I am understanding you right, then yes the sequence is already reversed.

Comment: @ymonad Bigint (neg1, zeros (sub' value1 value2 0)) I've actually just realized something that I should have realized a while before, the problem isn't with the larger number, its with the different lengths. You can see my zeros call, I now suspect that is where the error lies. I've added that to the main post if you want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I did not analyze your code completely, but I believe the problem is that division rounds to zero, while you would need it to round down. For example, `(-3) / 5 = 0` and `(-3) mod 5 = -3` while you would need `(-3) / 5 = -1` and `(-3) mod 5 = 2`.

It seems an invariant is `minus >= -radix`, so a simple fix would be to add `radix` to `minus` and adjust all else accordingly:

```
let minus = car1 - car2 + carry + radix
  in  minus mod radix :: sub' cdr1 cdr2 (minus / radix - 1)
```

This shifts the division and modulo into the nonnegative range, where it works as expected.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: in if diff < 0 then
          diff + radix :: sub' cdr1 cdr2 (0 - radix)
        else diff :: sub' cdr1 cdr2 0?